# how to remove a row in a table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
100100  Std. Scuba Tank, Yellow       Water Sports               650
100200  Std. Scuba Tank, Magenta      Water Sports               625
101100  Dive Mask, Small Clear        Water Sports               750
101200  Dive Mask, Med Clear          Water Sports               875
201000  Half-dome Tent                Camping                    262
202000  Half-dome Tent Footprint      Camping                    111
301000  Light Fly Climbing Harness    Climbing                   550
```

the respective columns are SKU, Description, Department, QuantityOnHand. My question is how to remove the last row which represents for the department that sells only one product?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What about `DELETE FROM ... WHERE Id = 301000` ?

Comment: I have tried count( distinct Description) != 1 but I don't think its the correct answer

Comment: my query to get that table is 
Select SKU_DATA.SKU, SKU_Description, Department, sum(quantityonhand) as numproducts

from SKU_DATA, INVENTORY

where SKU_DATA.SKU = INVENTORY.SKU and SKU_DATA.SKU != 302000

group by Department, SKU_DATA.SKU, SKU_Description

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
delete from your_table
where Department IN
(
  select Department 
  from your_table
  group by Department
  having count(distinct SKU) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE
FROM TableName
WHERE Department IN
    (SELECT Department
     FROM TableName
     GROUP BY Department
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SKU=1))
```